# How to add title plot in graphs that are produced in a loop with structure for

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with a database with various continuous variables and I have to do multiples graphs with ggplot2. When I made my loop I can't put the name of the variables at the main of each plot. My loop is the next:

```
library(ggplot2)
for(i in 1:10)
{
(qplot(Total, data = BaseClientes, geom = "histogram",binwidth = 50, fill = BaseClientes[,i])+geom_histogram(breaks =c(0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000,35000,40000)))
}
```

My problem is I have to add manually the names for each variable like this:

```
(qplot(Total, data = BaseClientes, geom = "histogram",binwidth = 50, fill = 4 Groups,main="4 Groups Monto Total")+geom_histogram(breaks =c(0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000,35000,40000)))
```

Where `4 groups` is the name of the variable. Is it possible to add inside for loop the name of each variable for all graphs. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion you're going the wrong way about the general problem (facetting sounds much more appropriate, and you should never have to use `BaseClientes[,i]` and the like in ggplot2). Could you perhaps post a representative dummy dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers already given would be the 'best practice', but if you necessarily to use `for` then you just need to notice the difference between `BaseClients[,i]` and `BaseClients[i]`. The second one will preserve its class

```
> df <- data.frame( var1 = 1:3, var2 = rnorm(3), var3 = sample(10,3))
> df
  var1        var2 var3
1    1 -0.29624838    9
2    2  0.08443593    4
3    3 -1.00889635    8

> class(df[,1])
[1] "integer"

> class(df[1])
[1] "data.frame"
```

and also its `names` attribute. In a nut shell try this:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  qplot(Total, data = BaseClientes, geom = "histogram",binwidth = 50,
        main = names(BaseClientes[i])) +
    geom_histogram(breaks =c(0,5000,10000,15000,20000,25000,30000,35000,40000))
}
```

Comment: probably I missed the 'fill' parameter

Answer (score 0):

Like @Baptiste said, just use facetting. An example:

```
ggplot(aes(x = mpg), data = mtcars) + 
    geom_histogram() + 
    facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image]

The structure of the data needs to be like `mtcars`, a sample of that dataset:

```
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```